# Vueify can't require component from node_modules

Tags: npm, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir

Here's my npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asva-vue-filters)

First, I install it.

```
npm install asva-vue-filters
```

Then I `require` the package from javascript file:

```
var vueFilters = require('asva-vue-filters')
```

And for some reason I get spammed by errors such as the following one (for every *.vue file in package):

```
gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] 
Browserify Failed!: Parsing file c:\homestead\pr5\node_modules\
asva-vue-filters\components\filters\sorting-order-filter.vue: 
Unexpected token (1:0)
```

But if I just copy the package folder from `node_modules` to some other place (e.g. project root), then I can `require` and everything works.

```
// Doesn't work
var vueFilters = require('./../../../../node_modules/asva-vue-filters/index')
// Works
var vueFilters = require('./../../../../asva-vue-filters/index')
```

Any ideas? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve an issue and here is how:

1. Remove `require('laravel-elixir-vueify')` from `gulpfile.js`.
2. Add browserify transforms to you package's `package.json`:

```
    "browserify": {
      "transform": [
        [
          "babelify",
          {
            "presets": [
              "es2015"
            ]
          }
        ],
        [
          "vueify"
        ]
      ]
    },
```

---

Alternatively, you can prepublish your package into digestible bundle that doesn't require browserify to function.